# How to setFloat a value of a PreparedStatement (jdbc) on NULL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, null, insert

I want to insert in my database lots of data with a Java program. I'm trying to manage the fact that the value of the String could be empty, in that way, I want to set the value to null.

This isn't working (`pstm.setFloat...`) :

```
PreparedStatement pstm;
try {
    pstm = connex.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO opfofa._produit_val_nut VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    pstm.setInt(1,id);
    pstm.setString(2,tabChaine[8]);
    pstm.setFloat(3,tabChaine[9].isEmpty()? null:Float.valueOf(tabChaine[9]));
    ...
    pstm.executeUpdate();
}catch(PSQLException e) {
    System.out.println("already inserted : "+e);
}
```

Error : java.lang.NullPointerException and that is normal because we can't set a float to null but in PostgreSQL I can set a Numeric column to null.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use setNull()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setFloat(int,%20float)) throws `NullPointerException` because it expects primitive `float` and not a `Float` object. You can try using [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) method instead - it allows using `null` values if needed. Something like:

```
pstm.setObject(3, tabChaine[9].isEmpty() ? null : Float.valueOf(tabChaine[9]), java.sql.Types.FLOAT);
```

Comment: Thats working thx !

Answer (score 2):

The code should look something like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstm;
try {
    pstm = connex.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO opfofa._produit_val_nut VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    pstm.setInt(1,id);
    pstm.setString(2,tabChaine[8]);
    if (tabChaine[9].isEmpty()) {
        pstm.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);
    }
    else {
        pstm.setFloat(3,Float.valueOf(tabChaine[9]));
    }
    ...
    pstm.executeUpdate();
}catch(PSQLException e) {
    System.out.println("already inserted : "+e);
}
```

More info on [setNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int))

Comment: Thats working too thx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [setNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) if you need to set a parameter null